# Is it possible to have one form/checkbox with three different actions?

Tags: html

I’m trying to create a webpage in which the user needs to check a checkbox in order to be able to click on any of the three subsequent links.

Is it possible to do in pure HTML?

Comment: It's kinda like you have to agree the terms in order to be able to click on links to other pages of the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would basically have a div that stays hidden and when the checkbox is clicked you would change the hidden property to false/true when it is unchecked.

In this hidden div you can put the 3 links.

```
function showDiv (box) {
    var chbox = document.getElementByName("checkbox");
    var visible = "none";

    if(chbox.checked){
        visible = "block";
        break;
    }

    chbox.setAttribute("disabled", "true");// you disable the checkbox here
    document.getElementById(box).style.display = visible;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So the action of checkbox/form should be set toggle the hidden property of the div?
Is it possible to make it happen just once? Like when the users checks the checkbox the div shows up and the checkbox can't be unchecked again?
I know it's too much, but is it possible in pure HTML?
Thanks again.

Comment: It is possible to block the checkbox after but I don't think it is possible in pure HTML though

Comment: edited the answer now you can have an idea on how it works. I think it is possible only with the help of JS

Comment: It isn't pure HTML, but it isn't complicated either. Thanks